# rxjs/Angular2 Loop but show different object of a single associative array

Tags: arrays, angular, rxjs6

I recently combined two array using rxjs

```
  MyArray =  [{
        "Field": ["Cars"],
        "Type": ["BMW", "Toyota", "Volvo"]
          },
         {
        "Field": ["House"],
        "Type": ["Condominium", "TownHouse"],
         }


   PriceArray = [
             {
            field: Cars,
            distribution: [{"name" : "BMW","price":2},{"name" : "Toyota","price":3}]
            },
            {
            field: People,
            distribution: [{"name" : "Condominium","price":3},{"name" : "TownHouse","price":2}]
           }]
```

using rxjs filter

```
const $MergeData = MyArray.map(val => {
  return Object.assign({}, val,this.PriceArray.filter(v => v.Field === val.field)[0])
});
 this.mergedArray = $MergeData;
```

Now it looked this..

```
mergedArray =  [{
    "Field": "Cars",
    "Type": ["BMW", "Toyota", "Volvo"],
    "field" : "Cars",
    "distribution" : [ 
        {
         "name" : "BMW"
         "price": 2 ,
        },
        {
         "name" : "Toyota"
         "price": 3 ,
        },
        {
         "name" : "Toyota"
         "price": 4 ,
        }
       ]
    }, .... (house array here)];
```

Then I tried to show the item price but its not working

```
<div *ngFor="let item of mergedArray">  
    <div *ngFor="let car of item.Field; let i = index"> 
        <p>{{car}} </p>
        <p>{{item.distribution.price[i]}} </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am hoping for a fix or better if the array should look like this instead

```
mergedArray =  [{
    "Field": "Cars",
     "Type": ["BMW": 2, "Toyota" : 3, "Volvo" : 4],
    }]
```

Hoping it would me possible as it is much easier to loop.

Comment: I don't really see where rxjs comes into play here -- it seems like these are just two arrays

Comment: Just few comments on your code, it's a good practice to use Object.Assing (or the `...` spread operator) to keep everything clean and avoid mutations, filter to search for some properties and so on, but I advice you to take a deeper look at the mdn documentation, so that you can enrich your js artillery, and as Explosion Pills mentioned this indeed is more like pureJS not rxjs.

Comment: Sorry I did not include the rxjs that results the output of priceArray

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is the desired effect, also keep in mind that when using `Array.prototype.filter` and no elements pass the test the returned value will be `[]` and if you try to access the `[][0]` element, the value will be `undefined`, after that if you try to access some property from that `undefined` value, it will throw an error.

For example if you try to access the price of Volvo it will throw an error `Cannot read property 'price' of undefined`, because Volvo doesn't exist in the `PriceArray`

```js
let priceArray = [ 
        {
         "name" : "BMW",
         "price": 2 
        },
        {
         "name" : "Toyota",
         "price": 3 
        },
        {
         "name" : "Toyota",
         "price": 4 
        }
       ];

let myArray =  [{
        "Field": "Cars",
        "Type": ["BMW", "Toyota", "Volvo"]}]

let findPrice= (priceArray,mark)=> priceArray
  .find(x=> x.name === mark) 
  ? priceArray.find(x=> x.name === mark).price 
  : 'No data'


let mergedArray = myArray[0].Type.map(x=> ({[x]:findPrice(priceArray,x)}))

console.log(mergedArray)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I forgot to show how field is important in the array.. I edited the arrays sorry.

Comment: Could you edit the code, I edited my question above with the correct arrays.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz demo with the problem, because i think that i don't fully understand your problem.